# How to achieve Canary release with sticky session in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, canary-deployment, servicemesh

I have used many solutions like Istio, spinnaker etc but they dont provide a way of performing Canary releases(weighted routing) and apply session affinity to stick to a particular pod.

You can achieve Canary feature, you can also achieve the session affinity (sticky session) on their own, but we cant achieve the combination of the two due to limitations in envoy proxy.

Is there any solution that provides Canary releases with session affinity feature for Kubernetes?

Answer (score 0):

ingress-nginx supports a wide variety of options for both of these. Traefik does too, though with more limited configurability.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor Nope, couldnt move away from Istio for various usecase, Istio doesnt support it yet  due to a limitation in Envoy. Moved to Dark Releases approach instead of Canary